# What will be the SQL select statement to identify the individuals who are listed as authors of each and every book in relation A

Tags: sql

Schema:

```
BID VAR-CHAR(40) NOT NULL,
AID VAR-CHAR(40) NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT PK PRIMARY KEY (BID, AID)
```

Instance:

```
bid    | aid  
-------+--------
Book 1 | Ada  
Book 1 | Bob  
Book 1 | Carl  
Book 2 | Ada  
Book 2 | Bob  
Book 2 | Carl 
Book 2 | Dave  
Book 3 | Carl
```

Using PostgreSQL
I want o find the author who has written every book in the database schema.

The output instance is

```
|aid|  
-----
|Carl|
```

Comment: This sounds like an academic exercise.  What have you tried?

Comment: I am not able to figure out how to chose an element for which it has a match in all the distinct bid, because one book has more than one author.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking what you can do is return the aid and group by the aid, but only return the aid if the distinct count of the bid is equal to 3 (since there are 3 books max and it has to be all 3 books). Try this maybe and let me know if it works?

```
SELECT aid
FROM bid
GROUP BY aid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(bid) = 3)
```